# Permanent repair on fuel tank

Tags: repair, fuel-tank

I have a 2003 Chrysler Town & Country 3.8L with a punctured (plastic) fuel tank.  I cannot find a replacement fuel tank.

~4 months ago I used a repair kit.  I cleaned the tank, used coarse sandpaper on the punctured spot, and then applied epoxy, fiberglass cloth, and more epoxy to seal the leak.  The puncture is 3mm-5mm (1/8th inch) in width.  Today, it failed and has begun leaking again.

I'm going to sand down the failed section, apply some "putty" (for fuel tanks) and then use another epoxy/fiberglass kit.  That should at least work in the short-term.

What are my options for a permanent solution?  Is there something more complex I could have a vehicle mechanic perform?  Are there replacement solutions I don't know about?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How big is the puncture?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the puncture width (3mm to 5mm).

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to "plastic weld" the puncture / cracks with a soldering iron.

Be careful to fill the tank with water and then have the tank oriented so the area to be repaired is uppermost - this reduces the amount of flammable gas.

Once the area has been "plastic welded" then I would reinforce the repaired area with the repair kit for strength. If you can find some extra plastic of the same type to use as a filler that would help.

I would, of course, start looking in a breakers or scrap yard for a replacement tank that is undamaged.